# Вызов общего метода у generic-класса с разными типами

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe2

Есть некий класс, допустим:

```
TListEx<T: TBaseClass> = class ...
  ....
  procedure Sort;
  ....
end;
```

и есть некое событие TNotifyEvent, где необходимо вызвать этот Sort:

```
procedure TMyForm.ListEvent(Sender: TObject);
begin 
  ....
  (Sender as ??????).Sort;
end;
```

Вопрос: что должно быть написано вместо "?????" ? Если туда написать `TListEx<TBaseClass>`, то при вызове метода с `Sender = TListEx<TExtClass>` (`TExtClass = class(TBaseClass)`) всё равно получаю ошибку несоответствия типов 'invalid class typecast'.

Но ведь метод-то всё равно общий? Как обойти данную неприятность?

Точнее, на данный момент я решил это как `TListEx<TBaseClass>(Sender).Sort`, но хотелось бы всё-таки сделать через `as` для надёжности.

Comment: вы бы еще воспроизводимый пример добавили, чтобы не приходилось за вас писать классы ([mcve])

Comment: формально, `TListEx<TBaseClass`> и `TListEx<TExtClass>` это совершенно разные  вещи (у них нет общего предка). У вас наследуется параметр, а не класс. Поэтому и не приводит его . Вот если бы вы написали `TListEx<T> = class(TListEx)` с методом `sort()` и приводили бы к нему, то все было бы нормально.

Comment: Да, наверное это хорошая идея, но в моём случае не подходит, т.к. Sort использует значения полей T;

Comment: вы его объявите абстрактным в базовом классе. и перекройте в `TListEx<T>`

Comment: Точно. Думаю можно в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял имеем следующее.
Классы параметры:

```
TBaseClass = class(TObject)
end;

TExtClass = class(TBaseClass)
end;
```

дженерик-класс списка:

```
TListEx<T> = class(TObject)
  public
    procedure Sort();
end;
```

и метод, принимающий аргумент - список:

```
procedure test(sender: TObject);
begin
   writeln(sender.ClassName);
  (sender as TListEx<BaseClass>).sort(); // invalid typcast
end;
```

тестовый вызов метода:

```
var l : TListEx<TExtClass>;
l := TListEx<TExtClass>.Create();
test(l);
```

При использовании дженериков компилятор для каждого из параметров создает свой класс. В итоге мы получаем 2 полностью  независимых класса `TListEx<TBaseClass>` и `TListEx<TExtClass>` не имеющих общего предка. Наследуются здесь только классы параметров, поэтому приведение типов не может быть выполнено.

Вы можете ввести базовый класс списка

```
TListEx = class(TObject)
   procedure Sort(); virtual; abstract;
end;
```

И унаследовать типизированный список от него. Тогда при приведении типа не потребуются знания о пераметре-`T`:

```
TListEx<T> = class(TListEx)
  public
    procedure Sort(); override;
end;

....
(Sender as TListEx).Sort();
```

Comment: у меня почему-то ощущение, что здесь что-то не так, и можно сделать иначе.